# Titanium auto simulate when editing

Tags: titanium, ios-simulator, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

How to setup titanium to auto update simulation when edit code like the first flash video on this link: http://www.appcelerator.com/product/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is called LiveView and is included in Appcelerator (not the deprecated Titanium) Studio. Request an invite on the new Appcelerator.com website for access to the new platform including AppC Studio. If you were already registered as Titanium developer before April 1st you get a free indie seat for life (normal price $39/month)